# UIViewController loading another view controller via xib, trying to access the default view causes crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, xib

So, I have this problem, that should be trivial..  I have a View Controller that is loading another view controller from a xib.  Trying to reference the view of that secondary view controller crashes with :

```
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "Embedded" nib but the view outlet was not set.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010689134b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
```

The code snippet that does this looks like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];

     // loads controller just fine.

     EbeddedViewController *embedded = [[EbeddedViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Embedded" bundle:nil];

     // KABOOM on line below 
     UIView *embeddedViewIs = embedded.view;

}
```

The EmbeddedViewController extends UIViewController, and it's very ordinary/plain..

```
#import "EbeddedViewController.h"

@interface EbeddedViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *embeddedLabel;

@end

@implementation EbeddedViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

@end
```

This is very boring and ordinary:

[image]

And this is the default view - I have tried adding an IBOutlet for it, but it crashes none-the-less.

[image]

The xib view controller is set up with the custom class properly:

[image]

I have no clue why this crashes..  If you wish to try this little app, please download it here:

[Link to a tiny two view controller app where this crash is demonstrated](https://slack-files.com/T02DTQP3H-F3AJVRR7V-3b9483cf19)

Comment: try to access the view in viewDidAppear method. Outlets are not yet set in the viewDidLoad method.

Comment: Thanks, for the response!  I did try to put that key piece of code - the loading of the xib in viewdidappear, and a crash happened exactly the same way - same thing.  Then I decided to split them - I put the loading of the xib in viewdidload, and accessing the view in viewdidappear, and it also crashed exactly the same way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you want to make the controller's view by using a xib, you shouldn't add a controller to the InterfaceBuilder, just add a view.
2. Select the File's Owner and set the custom class (EmbeddedViewController)
3. Connect the File's Owner's view outlet to the newly created view by control dragging from the File's Owner to the view as seen on the image

[image]